# ESP32-WROOM-32E Custom PCB. Code gets uploaded succesfully but doesn't work

Tags: pcb-design, esp32

We designed a custom PCB which has ESP32-WROOM-32E.

We first pushed our code onto a normal ESP32 DevKit commercial board to validate our code. There is no issue with the code. But when we push it to our custom PCB, the code gets uploaded but doesn't execute. The code that we are running is a simple script that sends "Hello world" over UDP.

In our schematic we had not grounded GPIO12, so we have to ground it manually while pushing the code for it to get uploaded. We are using an ESP32 Programmer to upload the code over RX/TX.

Voltage Levels across each pin after upload:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AA_lTx20qFXUZxxS0GDzUBGCM-w9KIyeTWfhpximsV0/edit#gid=0

ESP32WROOM 32E Datasheet:https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-wroom-32e_esp32-wroom-32ue_datasheet_en.pdf

Attaching schematic.
[image]

Comment: Welcome! What have you verified so far? Are all voltages present and of right value? Is your ESP32 enabled and set to boot?

Comment: the code does get uploaded without any errors on the IDE, so we are assuming the booting part is not the issue.

Comment: Don't assume. Measure and be sure.

Comment: who do you reckon we measure specifically ?

Comment: Enable the *'Debugging Log Print'* feature.

Comment: And are you sure this doesn't apply: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNefM.png

Comment: Have you measured VDD_SDIO?

Comment: All rail voltages, EN pin, IO0 (boot) pin.

Comment: @Velvel Will Debugging Log print work via rx tx, we don't have a dedicated port for data communication we were using Rx Tx. 

2. That doesn't apply for ESP32E It doesn't have embedded PS RAM: https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-wroom-32e_esp32-wroom-32ue_datasheet_en.pdf

3. Don't know where the VDD_SDIO is in this chip: https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-wroom-32e_esp32-wroom-32ue_datasheet_en.pdf

This is the datasheet.

Comment: When the 'Debugging Log Print' feature is enabled (MTDO/GPIO15 = pulled up), the device will use U0TXD to send log messages during bootup.

Comment: You said you had to pull GPIO12 to GND to be able to program the device. This means VDD_SDIO has to be configured for 3.3V. Does the firmware configure VDD_SDIO for 3.3V?

Comment: Try to remove C11. This capacitor can hold GPIO0 low during power on reset and the firmware expects a new download.

Comment: Please post it in your original question, not as off-site links.

Comment: @Jens GPIO0 after the download is giving 2.93V on measuring with a multimeter which is a digital high or does it need to be synchronized and capacitors are affecting the synchronization?

Comment: @Jens removed capacitors, but still no luck. No errors in downloading the code. But doesn't execute afterwards. We are having to press the boot button to push the code. So it's not always set to boot by default. That switch is happening. But it doesn't execute the pushed code.

Comment: There is a lot of hardware and software involved to send a packet via UDP. Can you use a much simpler blink program to exclude power supply issues and I2C deadlocks? Does the program start after a power cycle?

Comment: @Jens we tried simply turning pin 25 to digital high for lighting an LED. The measured voltage across pin 25 after pushing the code. It is still at a digital low, some 1.1V instead of being a digital high close to 3.3V.  No errors in Arduino IDE while uploading the code.

Comment: Could you post your code? Just looking at the circuit, I would suggest adding a 10k pullup resistor on GPIO0. Yeah, 2.93V is higher than 0.75VDD but it's still a bit lower than I would expect. Could also probe GPIO0 and EN with an oscilloscope and see if the voltage is dropping causing brownouts.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was happening because R3 resistor connected to SDA was pulled up. It prevented ESP from entering execution mode because SDA is connected to IO12 which is MTDI (It's a strapping pin supposed to be left floating).

Using another SDA pin should fix it.

Comment: It's not necessary to use another SDA pin. You just have to configure `VDD_SDIO` appropriately within the firmware (as I commented on your question). See https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvH4E.png.